# how can Edit a block code after running in python IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x

Im new in python.
I run this code:

```py
x=5
y="john"
print(x)
```

now I need to edit `x=5` to `x="jack"`
how can I edit this block code in python IDLE 3.10.7?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit/undo a command that has already executed. You can reexecute and modify any lines you've entered in the terminal though by pressing the up-arrow key on your keyboard.

Click once: `print(x)` should be visible on the terminal.

Click again and: `y="john"` should be visible.
Now you can move the cursor with the 'left/right' arrow keys and replace the `y` with a `x`. Press enter.

Now press up two times: `print(x)` should be visible. When you execute that command you'll see `x` is `"john"` now.

Hope that helped. Good luck with python.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous as to if you are referring to the editor itself or reassignment of values in the code.

If it is the editor, then just `open the python file`, edit it and save the changes.

If it is changing the values of variables then:

You can reassign a new value or string to a variable like this:

```py
x=5
y="john"
print(x)


# edit variable
x = "jack"
print(x)
```